# ActionController::UnknownFormat only on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In the heroku logs I see the following.

```
app[web.1]: Started GET "/tags/1" ...
app[web.1]: Processing by TagsController#show as HTML
app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
app[web.1]:   Tag Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
app[web.1]: Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
app[web.1]: ActionController::UnknownFormat (TagsController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.
app[web.1]: request.formats: ["text/html"]
app[web.1]: request.variant: []
```

In dev env the page is rendering fine and I don't see the error.

```
> ls app/views/tags
_form.html.haml new.html.haml   show.html.haml
```

Controller

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :show

  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id].to_i)
  end
  ...
```

Comment: What is *request format* coming to `show` action? Seems like it is not *HTML*.

Comment: yeah, I'm guessing it's either a JSON or JS request

Comment: It is HTML. I added more of the log output in the question

Comment: Ok. It *IS HTML*. Also I can see you have `show.html.haml`. Can you confirm it again that `show.html.haml` is present inside the `app/views/tags`?

Comment: Not sure how I can prove it more than the `ls` output and the fact that it loads in local development

Comment: Did you checked on the *production env* too? Did the file exists in `app/views/tags`?

Comment: my global gitignore was ignoring the tags dir because that's the same dir name that vim uses for ctags. Error messages do not lie, the views weren't there. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, how did you solved your problem?

Comment: remove `tags` from `~/.gitignore_global`

Comment: I just had the exact same problem. Can't believe how lucky I am to have found your question and its comments. Thank you!